# EmberJS - Refactoring item into a Component stops Query Params and actions triggering

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I currently have a small report builder in my application that updates query params in the URL. The query params are used to define criteria in a query on my back end and return the required report.

I am trying to refactor it into a component so that it can be used in other parts of the application.

Here is the report builder:

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top:100px">

  <div class="panel panel-info">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">Report Builder</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <form class="form-horizontal" method="get" {{action "submitQuery" dateFrom dateTo unitNumber on="submit"}}>
        <div class="form-group">

          <div class="col-sm-3"><label>Module:</label>
            {{#select-box/native value=sb on-select=(action 'selected') class="form-control" as |sb| }}
              {{sb.option value='Select a Module:'}} {{sb.option value='Option 1 List'}} {{sb.option value="Option 2 List" }} {{sb.option value="Option 3 List" }} {{sb.option value="Option 4 List" }}
            {{/select-box/native}}
          </div>

          <div class="col-sm-3"><label>Date From:</label>{{pikaday-input locale=en value=dateFrom  format='DD/MM/YYYY' class="form-control" name="dateFrom" onSelection=(action 'onChangeDateFrom') }}</div>
          <div class="col-sm-3"><label>Date From:</label>{{pikaday-input value=dateTo  format='DD/MM/YYYY' class="form-control" name="dateTo" onSelection=(action 'onChangeDateTo') }}</div>
          <div class="col-sm-3"><label>Unit Number:</label>{{input type="text" value=unitNumber class="form-control" name="unitNumber" }}</div>
          <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-5" style="margin-top:15px">
            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here are the actions that are used to set the query params for the query and take the user to the correct page afterwards. This code is on the controller for the reports.hbs template:

```
import Controller from '@ember/controller';

export default Controller.extend({

  queryParams: ['dateFrom', 'dateTo', 'unitNumber'],
  dateFrom: null,
  dateTo: null,
  unitNumber: null,

  actions: {
    selected(x) {
      module = x
    },

    onChangeDateFrom(selectedValue) {
      this.set('dateFrom', moment(selectedValue).format('DD-MM-YYYY'))

    },

    onChangeDateTo(selectedValue) {
      this.set('dateTo', moment(selectedValue).format('DD-MM-YYYY'))

    },

    submitQuery(dateFrom, dateTo, unitNumber) {
      switch (module) {
        case 'Option 1 List':
          this.transitionToRoute('option1list', {
            queryParams: {
              dateFrom: this.get('dateFrom'),
              dateTo: this.get('dateTo'),
              unitNumber: this.get('unitNumber')
            }
          })
          break;
        case 'Option 2 List':
          this.transitionToRoute('opton2list', {
            queryParams: {
              dateFrom: this.get('dateFrom'),
              dateTo: this.get('dateTo'),
              unitNumber: this.get('unitNumber')
            }
          })
          break;
        case 'Option 3 List':
          this.transitionToRoute('option3list', {
            queryParams: {
              dateFrom: this.get('dateFrom'),
              dateTo: this.get('dateTo'),
              unitNumber: this.get('unitNumber')
            }
          })
          break;
        case 'Option 4 List':
          this.transitionToRoute('opton4list', {
            queryParams: {
              dateFrom: this.get('dateFrom'),
              dateTo: this.get('dateTo'),
              unitNumber: this.get('unitNumber')
            }
          })
          break;
        case 'Select a Module:':
          alert('Please select a Module')
          break;
        default:
          console.log('error')
      }
    }
  }
});
```

When I create a component (report-builder) and put in the HTML the fields and actions no longer operate. Attempting to copy the actions into the report-builder.js also doesn't work

transitionToRoute cannot be used in a component either. I tried to separate the actions into the JS file for the component and the transitions into a controller called report-builder but this did not produce any results.

I am new to Ember and Software Development, any advice is gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass all the actions from controller to component.

In reports.js controller file,

```
actions:{
  submitQuery(){
    //subit query code
  }
}
```

In reports.hbs file,

```
{{report-builder submitQuery=(action 'submitQuery') }}
```

In report-builder.hbs file,

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" {{action submitQuery}}>Submit</button>
```

On clicking submit button will trigger method `submitQuery` in controller.

You can read more info [triggering-changes-with-actions](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.16.0/components/triggering-changes-with-actions/)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think I can see how that works. When I implement the above I receive an error that says 'selected' was not found in report-builder. If I append selected=(action 'selected') I receive the same error. If I understand the documentation correctly I should be able to send two actions from the statement. I would imagine I'd have the same problem with inChangedateFrom and onChangeDateTo. I suspect its because the actions above are in a block helper which is acting as its own component?

Comment: Try sample ember-twiddle.com and share the url, it will help us to answer. {{action helper will wrap the function in the current context, here context is report-builder component, so it will expect that functions should be defined in actions hash of the report-builder component.

Comment: I've not used ember Twiddle before, I hope this is what you are looking for https://ember-twiddle.com/a5ddb668fb377c9596a3fa05ac0b6f5e?openFiles=controllers.reports.js%2C - I've added the project 'as is' with a commented line with the code you supplied in report-builder.hbs

Comment: We need very minimal working example. I included very minimum [working twiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47574601/emberjs-refactoring-item-into-a-component-stops-query-params-and-actions-trigg/47587267)